# My Tomcat server occasionally unresponsive

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a tomcat server running an OA system. Recently i found the server intermittently became unresponsive and even stopped serving static resources.

When it happens, the server throws no exceptions, no full GC.

The only weird thing is the output of `netstat -n | awk '/^tcp/ {++S[$NF]} END {for(a in S) print a, S[a]}'`, the result shows the tomcat process holds a lot of TCP connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` state.

Here is the output:

```
TIME_WAIT 85
CLOSE_WAIT 1110
SYN_SENT 1
FIN_WAIT2 69
ESTABLISHED 207
```

Here is the output of command `lsof -p 27564`

```
java    27564 username  284u  IPv6          752174883       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10689 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  285u  IPv6          752174887       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10691 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  286u  IPv6          752174894       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10693 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  287u  IPv6          752174891       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10692 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  288u  IPv6          752174900       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10695 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  289u  IPv6          752174897       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10694 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  290u  IPv6          752175319       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10857 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  291u  IPv6          752174903       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10697 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  292u  IPv6          752174909       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10698 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  293u  IPv6          752174912       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10700 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    27564 username  294u  IPv6          752174916       0t0       TCP myip:9090->myip:10701 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

These ports(10689, 10691...) owns by the same java process.

The most strange things is after six or seven minutes, everything go back to normal.

I don't understand why there are TCP connections in one process?

Can any explain to me?

Comment: I can only guess, but it seems the application opens network connections maybe to a database or so locally and does not clean up connections properly when done. Reasons are plenty. Check if the app swallows exceptions, too (i.e. empty catch-blocks).

Comment: @Fildor My database server is on another host. Thanks for your suggestions, i will check.